# Why the counter does not work in threadpool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I made a simple application using the threadpool, but when I do the counter inside or outside the threadpool, it just returns zero in all cases or Non - sequential numbers?

My program [ I am sending 10 thousand valuable webrequest [API] and I knew that threadpool faster way?
Because I want to send and receive 10,000 request within 5 to 10 minutes. ]

```
    public int Count;

    private void TaskCallBack(Object ThreadNumber)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Count.ToString());  

        Interlocked.Increment(ref Count);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //// Queue the task.
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(TaskCallBack));
            }

            this.Count = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding breakpoints on `this.Count = 0;` and `MessageBox.Show(Count.ToString());`.

Comment: You are assigning the value of Count to 0. You might want to initialize the Count to 0 in the first line and remove the line: this.Count = 0;

Comment: i tried brakpoint , same error still 0 after loop

Comment: Classic threading race bug, this one repeats very well.  You can't click 10 OK buttons fast enough to let all ten threads progress to the Increment() call.  After which none are left to still call Count.ToString().  The Interlocked class is no substitute for `lock`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can have 10 threads all print out the initial value of `Count` before any one of them increments the value.  There's no guarantee of consecutive order, either, should threads increment `Count` prior to other threads calling `Show`.  To get both, use a mutex to control concurrent access to your callback's logic:

```
    public int Count;
    private readonly object _countLock = new Object();

    private void TaskCallBack(Object ThreadNumber)
    {
        lock( _countLock )
        {
            ++Count;
            MessageBox.Show(Count.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // this smells
            this.Count = 0;

            //// Queue the task.
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(TaskCallBack));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same problem , i have array list and i want this count move from 0 to 10

Comment: It doesn't matter if the numbers are arranged or not, but it's important to be non-dublicate and within the 10 numbers

Comment: @hashembaddad I think you need to show more code if you're still having a problem

Answer (score 0):

When you use the [`Interlocked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked) class to manipulate a variable, then all access to this variable must be done through the `Interlocked` class. Otherwise there is no guarantee that you'll get the current value of the variable. So, for starters, the `Count` variable should not be made `public`.

```
private int _count;

public int Count => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _count, 0, 0);

private void TaskCallBack(Object ThreadNumber)
{
    var localCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
    MessageBox.Show(localCount.ToString());
}
```

Comment: As a side note, calling the `MessageBox` class from any thread other than the UI thread is a bad idea. Using a `BackgroundWorker` just to schedule some work in the `ThreadPool` is a bad idea too. In general, doing multithreading before obtaining a firm grip of the concepts is not recommended. There are just too many things that can go wrong.

Comment: thank you , i tried this but same error when i set array list index to counter  just give me same thing [0] every time